# python - convert UTC timestamp to unixtime

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I'm trying to convert my timestamp to unixtime paying attention to it not being UTC however the unixtime is incorrect.

```
import time
import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse

time_str = '2017-03-09T15:44:40.000-05:00'

time_obj = parse(time_str)

print time_obj

unixtime = time.mktime(time_obj.timetuple())

print unixtime
```

The unixtime it returns is `1489092280.0` which represents to `03/09/2017 @ 8:44pm (UTC)` when what I want is `1489074280`.

Comment: just doing `int(unixtime)` does not work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`time.mktime` expects a broken-down local time and treats input as such, i.e. converts it to UTC and then builds a seconds-since-epoch timestamp. Since you already have the broken-down UTC time, you need to call `calendar.timegm` instead:

```
>>> unixtime = calendar.timegm(time_obj.timetuple())
>>> print unixtime
1489074280
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your result was correct. 15:44 in -05:00 timezone is 20:44 (ie. 8:44 pm) in UTC.